# unable to remove default kafka configuration in cloudera

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera

In a PoC cloudera cluster provided with kafka(1 broker) I'm trying to send messages to the cluster with an external producer through a public IP. My cluster nodes are hosted in Azure and all of them are reachable from my local machine where the external producer is running.

Following this great article https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ I figured out the kafka listeners config I need as this broker public IP is only reachable from my local machine and inside the cluster they can only communicate using their internal hostnames:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://internal-broker-node-hostname:19092,EXTERNAL://public-broker-ip:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

With this configuration when I try to start the broker I get this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Only one of inter.broker.listener.name and security.inter.broker.protocol should be set.
```

Which makes sense as in Kafka doc for this property `inter.broker.listener.name` they say:

> Name of listener used for communication between brokers. If this is unset, the listener name is defined by security.inter.broker.protocol. It is an error to set this and security.inter.broker.protocol properties at the same time.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to unset `security.inter.broker.protocol` through the cloudera manager as I only have the option of switching options in a radio button.

[image]

How can I unset that property?

Comment: Might be a better question for Cloudera support forums since it's specific problem to Cloudera Manager... Have you looked at the actual property file on disk, though? `INFERRED` is not a valid Kafka option

Answer (score 0):

Internal and external are just strings

So, you could set PLAINTEXT for CDH and just redefine the external listener as being advertised

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT 
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://internal-broker-node-hostname:19092,EXTERNAL://public-broker-ip:9092
```

You'll also want to make sure your external broker IPs are static

Comment: If this doesn't work, Azure Event Streams or the Confluent Azure images might make more sense from a PoC perspective